# Is it acceptable to redirect users to your company's help desk when they ask about your product?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I was reviewing late answers when [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593949/anycharts-ratio-of-bars-in-the-bar-charts-is-not-proper/25362219#25362219) popped up. After suggesting a solution to the question, the answerer says:

> Hope this helps.
>
> If not, please contact the anychart support team via email: support@anychart.com and provide the details of your issue (xml data).

What is the proper way to deal with this? Is it okay to give a vague answer and ask the user to submit a ticket to your company's help desk?

If that's the case, the solution to that question is going to be lost somewhere between the user and the help desk, leading to questions with incomplete answers.

Comment: This not a duplicate,  that question is about companies redirecting users from their websites to stackoverflow,  my question is about redirecting users from stackoverflow to the company support website

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The part of that answer asking users to send an email or open a support ticket doesn't answer the question, so I edited it out. I've also left a comment asking them not to do that.

Comment: I don't see a comment.

Comment: @RahilWazir The user agreed, so both comments were deleted by a mod.

Comment: It seems wrong to remove such info if it may help users. I sometimes include a link to Python bug tracker for [tag:python] questions e.g., [a question that exposes a bug in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13479295/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian If a bug is already reported, I think it's fine to include a link as part of a complete answer. If you're just suggesting someone open a bug report I think that's better left in the comments (as you did in your example). The example here was neither, it was just an email address, which doesn't help anyone else who has the same problem.

Comment: @Bill - I'm not sure I agree with your position on this question. User "anychart support" provided the answer with code, and then provided an email address in case there's a problem. In this case, I don't find anything wrong with the formulation of the answer. It would be a different story if they *only* provided the link to email support, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @jww There's no reason to include your email address in an answer ever. I don't see why this case would be any different from every other Q&A on the site.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: This isn't a help site.

Comment: @jww: Looks like you think this is a help site where anything goes as long as someone is "helped".

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - no, I don't.

Comment: What if the user is unaware there is a dedicated support website and/or they are entitled to such support.  I don't see how this wouldn't potentially help every single person who has an issue with that product.

Comment: @Kik As I already said, it's not an answer to the question so it belongs in the comments.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Does this fall under the same reasoning? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25388544/525478

Answer (score 6):

If it's appropriate, you might consider directing your company's help desk to the SO question. That way the user gets helped, but an answer is preserved for future users (and more easily searchable).

Comment: I'd say answering the general case, and asking them to raise a support ticket for their specifics might be acceptable. E.g. if there's a known bug that the vendor can hotfix or workaround.